# Creating sorted Hash Table

Tags: sorting, hashtable

Using the keys (60, 120, 48, 12, 210, 83, 10, 30, 400, 38, 5, 8)

Create a sorted hash table.

h_i(k) = (h(k) + i) % table_length h(k) = k % table_length

What does sorted mean? like 0--5, 1--8, 2--10, ……. 11--400   ?

Comment: Why don't I get any answers?

Comment: I’m not familiar with the term “sorted hash table,” and I’ve spent a lot of time exploring different types of hash tables. What is the context of this question? Also, is this a homework question?

Comment: Yes it is a homework question. I also couldn't find much when i searched. Maybe it just means hash table?

Comment: If it’s a homework question, I’d recommend asking your instructor. I’ve never come across the term before.

Comment: Thanks… I will do it as a regular hash table. So, as far as I understood, k here is input (60, 120, 48, 12, 210, 83, 10, 30, 400, 38, 5, 8) And first I will try this h(k) = k % table_length to find the the place to map the given number k, if there is a conflict then I will use h_i(k) = (h(k) + i) % table_length? And will I do this with a for loop like h_1, h_2 …. until I find an empty slot?

Comment: I learned what a sorted hash table is, if you want to know

Comment: Sure - what’s a sorted hash table?